# Plot individual countries with matlab mapping toolbox

Tags: matlab

I would like to draw a map of specific countries in matlab using the mapping toolbox. Specifically, I would like to draw a map of Austria and Switzerland only.

I have tried the following:

```
ax = worldmap({'Austria','Switzerland'});
land = shaperead('landareas', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(ax, land, 'FaceColor', [0.5 0.7 0.5])
lakes = shaperead('worldlakes', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(lakes, 'FaceColor', 'blue')
rivers = shaperead('worldrivers', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(rivers, 'Color', 'blue')
```

which produces

[image]

However, I would like something that looks more like [this](http://www.holidaysonlocation.com/image/map/at_ch.jpg), which is the countries specified, without the other European countries included in the figure. Is this possible in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, yes, but you would need another shapefile, containing information about the individual countries.

`worldmap` only sets the boundaries of the map.  The other information you plot comes out of the shapefile you load and doesn't check what countries you set in `worldmap` - and even if it did, couldn't do anything with the information, because if you check `land` you'll see the individual countries in Europe aren't listed.  You could either get specific shapefiles just for those two countries, or get a shapefile containing something like data for all Europe and just pull out details of those two countries from it.

A simple example for the US using builtin data: this loads a set of data about all states but extracts and plots only Texas:

```
ax = worldmap({'USA'});
land = shaperead('usastatehi', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
n = strcmp({land.Name},'Texas');
geoshow(ax, land(n))
```